# How to write a function that takes a function f and a float x and applies f to x k times using Swift?

Tags: swift

I want to solve this

```
  Write a function applyKTimes(f:(Float -> Float),x:Float,k:Int) -> Float 
  that takes a function f and a float x and applies f to x k times
```

for example the function f is

```
 func square (number:Float) -> Float
 {
      return number * number
 }
```

is there a short solution using Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive solution:

```
func applyKTimes(f:(Float -> Float), x:Float, k:Int) -> Float
{
  return k > 0 ? applyKTimes(f, f(x), k - 1) : x
}
```

I have not checked if Swift guarantees tail call optimization. If it does, than the recursive solution is what you really want. However if it does not you need to unroll it by hand to avoid problems with the stack.

The same, but unrolled by hand:

```
func applyKTimes(f:(Float -> Float), x:Float, k:Int) -> Float
{
    var result = x
    for _ in 0..k {
       result = f(result)
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. You need a `:` and an 'else' clause.

Comment: Xcode error `Expected ':' after '? ...' in ternary expression`

Comment: Yes, sorry. I had hit post too early, I was not finished writing. I have corrected that and completed the answer with the unrolled version. Tell me if there still is something wrong: I do not have the Swift compiler here, so I'm going by heart.

Comment: lol, I'm too much used to Haskell. I had forgotten the '(' and ')' in the call to `f` :P

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use recursion:

```
func applyKTimes(f:(Float -> Float), x: Float, k: Int) -> Float {
    var result = x
    for _ in 0..k {
        result = f(result)
    }
    return result
}
```